# Angular ngIf else is not working inside ng-container

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Am trying to implement ngif else in Angular12. But for some reason else part is not getting executed.The problem is if the image is not null it has to generate the cards with image. If the image is null i want some text inside the card mentioning "IMAGE NOT AVALIABLE".The else part is not working.can someone steer me in the right direction. Thanks

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="seasonsdetail.season?.length">
      <ng-container *ngFor = "let seasons of seasonsdetail.season">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
          <ng-container *ngIf="seasons.image.medium; else elseTemplate">
            <div class="card" data-id='' >
                <a href= ''><img class="card-img img-fluid " [src]='seasons.image.medium' alt="Seasons"></a>
            </div>
            <h4 class="card-title">
              {{seasons.number}}
            </h4>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
        <ng-template #elseTemplate>
          <div class="card" data-id='' >
            <!--<div class="card-body"> -->
              <h4>Image not Avaliable</h4>
            <!--</div>-->
          </div>
          <h4 class="card-title">
            {{seasons.number}}
         </h4>         
        </ng-template>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-template>
```

Comment: Maybe include a screenshot of what it looks like?

Comment: Hi, can you provide sample data in the question with the `image` is null and not null case? Thank you.

Comment: @Yong Shun Am trying to access an API. The response sometimes contains image and most of the times null.. So i want to render my page based on the presence of the image.If image is there render the iamge else render empty card with custom message.

Comment: In case image is possible null, you may use `seasons.image?.medium` as `?` is optional chaining in Typescript, it will only access to `medium` if `image` is not null, otherwise it will bypass and treat as null.

Comment: @YongShun Thanks..I tried this.. [src]='seasons.image?seasons.image.medium:"assets/img/noimage.png"'. But its still not rendering the  noimage.png. Am i doing something wrong.

Comment: @yongShun Thanks.. Its working now.. I removed the container with condition. Instead I implemented the chaining operator ?.

Comment: Hi @Karthik, good to see you get the desired result. Meanwhile, I had added my answer with 2 solutions. You may choose either one that best suits you. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ISSUE

From the question, `seasons.image` is possible to be null.

It works when `seasons.image` is **not null**, thus you can access `seasons.image.medium`.

However, when `seasons.image` is **null** and you don't handle for null scenario, you will get this error and the `#elseTemplate` is not generated.

> ERROR Error: Cannot read property 'medium' of null

---

### SOLUTION 1

You have to apply [Typescript Optional Chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) to handle the null scenario for `seasons.image`.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="seasons.image?.medium; else elseTemplate">
```

Full HTML template:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="seasonsdetail.season?.length">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let seasons of seasonsdetail.season">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <ng-container *ngIf="seasons.image?.medium; else elseTemplate">
        <div class="card" data-id=''>
          <a href=''><img class="card-img img-fluid " [src]='seasons.image.medium' alt="Seasons"></a>
        </div>
        <h4 class="card-title">
          {{seasons.number}}
        </h4>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
    <ng-template #elseTemplate>
      <div class="card" data-id=''>
        <!--<div class="card-body"> -->
        <h4>Image not Avaliable</h4>
        <!--</div>-->
      </div>
      <h4 class="card-title">
        {{seasons.number}}
      </h4>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

[Solution 1 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pfvmmj)

---

### SOLUTION 2

Based on your latest comment, you try to discard the `#elseTemplate` and handle for null `sessions.image` in the same `ngContainer`. Yes, you can do in that way.

**And you need to remove `ngIf` logic from the `ngContainer`.**

```
<img class="card-img img-fluid " [src]='seasons.image ? seasons.image.medium : "assets/img/noimage.png">
```

Full HTML Template

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="seasonsdetail.season?.length">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let seasons of seasonsdetail.season">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <ng-container>
        <div class="card" data-id=''>
          <a href=''><img class="card-img img-fluid " [src]='seasons.image ? seasons.image.medium : "assets/img/noimage.png"' alt="Seasons"></a>
        </div>
        <h4 class="card-title">
          {{seasons.number}}
        </h4>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

[Solution 2 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ieffwg)

Answer (score -1):

You might wrap your container with another template then you can add the If condition to the ng-template (see example below).

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="seasons.image.medium; else noImage">
   <ng-container>
      Image code here
   </ng-container>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #noImage>
  no image code here
</ng-template>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But now if condition is also not rendering..